# json parsing from an url in phonegap app for an android mobiles

Tags: javascript, android, json, parsing, cordova

Hi friends so far i have been worked only in android native app. First time i am trying to create an app in Phone gap for android devices.

I want to `hit an url` and there i get a return data in `json` format. I dont know to write a code in `javascript` to hit an URL and get back a return data. Please help me by giving a piece of code or any tutorial to hit an url and get the return data. From that returned data i need to do json parsing, pls guide me in `json parsing in javascript` too.

Please help me friends......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tutorial of this on the phonegap wiki:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

It just what you are looking for :)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are trying to do a request using GET or POST. You just need to use `JSONRequest`

If you are trying to just use a simple GET request then your syntax would look something like this:

```
requestNumber = JSONRequest.get(
    "http://yourdomainname.com/request", 
    function (requestNumber, value, exception) {
        if (value) {
            processResponse(value);
        } else {
            processError(exception);
        }
    }
);
```

If you are wanting to use POST and you need to send some information here is an example for that:

```
requestNumber = JSONRequest.post(
    "http://yourdomainname.com/request", 
    {
        username: "user",
        action: "actionname"
    }, 
    function (requestNumber, value, exception) {
        if (value) {
            processResponse(value);
        } else {
            processError(exception);
        }
    }
);
```